# jQuery Stickysidebar overlaying on footer

Tags: jquery, overlay, footer, sticky

I am using the jQuery stickybox plugin. Here is the plugin's website:
http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/sticky-sidebar-jquery-plugin/

Here is my page:
http://dev.erfolgsphoto.de/test/index.html

The problem is, on my page, you can see the sliding box is overlaying on footer but I want it to do not overlay on footer. The sliding box should be in the parent DIV (DIV with class "body-container-main"). The example on the plugin's site (please see example with multiple sticky boxes) is also working as I am expecting. But my code is not working as expected.

Comment: You can see this example for what I want:
http://www.profilepicture.co.uk/demos/stickybox/multi.php

This example shows that the sliding will be inside it's parent DIV.

Comment: i'm reading this example... i'm looking for the difference with your code

Comment: Do you mean that you want the sliding box to stay within the `body-container-main` but instead it rolls over the footer area as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 97 of `stickysidebar.jquery.js`, the plugin is looping over all the parent elements of your sticky sidebar. The comment mentions:

> go up the tree until we find an elem to position from

The very first element it retrieves from the call to `.parent()` inside that loop is your div "wrapper". The subsequent is `body` followed by `html`. The element that it considers first is **not** `body-container-main`.

When `$this.parent()` gets called on line 79, it **does** refer to the container div that you intended. What should really be happening is that that loop on line 97 should never get going. That means that one of the three conditions needs to be false. I propose that you make the `$parent.css("position")` something other than "static". In your example page for the stickybox multi, they have laid out the parent divs as `position:absolute` and `position:relative`. The shopping cart / basket's `parent()` div is `position:static` so that one ends up sticking to the entire page.

Change your parent div's `position` css property to `relative`.

Applicable sections of code for others:

```
// 'Line 75' of the plugin code here
var setPosition = function ($sb) {
if ($sb) {
  var $this = $sb
    , $parent = $this.parent() // **line 79**
    , parentOffs = $parent.offset()
    , currOff = $this.offset()
    , data = $this.data("stickySB");
  if (!data) {
    data = {
        offs: {} // our parents offset
      , orig: { // cache for original css
            top: $this.css("top")
          , left: $this.css("left")
          , position: $this.css("position")
          , marginTop: $this.css("marginTop")
          , marginLeft: $this.css("marginLeft")
          , offset: $this.offset()
        }
    }
  }
  //go up the tree until we find an elem to position from
  while (parentOffs && "top" in parentOffs // **line 97**
    && $parent.css("position") == "static") {
    $parent = $parent.parent();
    parentOffs = $parent.offset();
  }
  if (parentOffs) { // found a postioned ancestor
    var padBtm = parseInt($parent.css("paddingBottom"));
    padBtm = isNaN(padBtm) ? 0 : padBtm;
    data.offs = parentOffs;
    data.offs.bottom = settings.constrain ?
      Math.abs(($parent.innerHeight() - padBtm) - $this.outerHeight()) :
      $(document).height();
  }
  else data.offs = { // went to far set to doc
      top: 0
    , left: 0
    , bottom: $(document).height()
  };
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have applied "position:relative" to ".body-container-main" div and now it's working perfectly. Thanks again :)

Comment: The height of the ".body-container-main" div was set to 2000px but I have changed it to "auto" (to match my working site's code structure) and now again it's not working. Can you please look at it?

Comment: @BimalRekhadiya, the plugin might not support keeping the sliding div inside an outer div of unknown height (auto). You'll have to work through the plugin code to find a way around it _or_ specify the height of the container. Line 106-108 is where it decides how far to let the div slide down. You can use your browser's developer tools to set a breakpoint there and see what values it is deciding upon **and** what is available.